# Custom field / form field (maybe widget?) for storing values for a string format

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I wish to create a model where I can store a string formatting pattern as well as accompanying values.

Example:

```
Pattern = 'Strength deals %d more damage for each %f%% critical chance'
Values = [2, 1.50]
```

The pattern only has to store `int`s and `float`s. My initial thought was to simply create a custom field, validate the values and that would be it. You can see my field [here](https://gist.github.com/cpnielsen/6673959)

However, this simply lets me save the list. I still need some way to figure out how many values to validate, check that it matches the other field (a simple `CharField`). This could be done "manually", but I would like to create a custom form field that would generate X input boxes that match the number of wildcards in the pattern.

Question 1: Is there any way to "link" two fields so that one can act on the value of the other?

Question 2: To create this, I would probably need to create a new form widget, but is this possible? Any hints as to how to start?

Answer (score 1):

This may not exact answer, but writing it in comment is not feasible.

Another option would to store as JSON string in the model. Like

```
[{ "Pattern": 'Strength deals %d more damage for each %f%% critical chance',
  "Values" : [2, 1.50]
}]
```

Use custom form field to input/output as JSON input. There are quite a few implementation available when searched on google.

With this approach, you can try to validate the inputs, so that format string and number of variables provided matches.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but the solution I went with I have 2 seperate models - one with the pattern and another with a foreignkey relation that then uses the pattern + inserts values.